# Como puedo borrar clientes en función del nombre? y despúes buscar clientes según su nombre

Tags: java

Tengo un problema con los métodos `buscarClientes` y `borrarClientes`: no sé cómo puedo borrar un cliente por su nombre y luego tampoco me sale cómo puedo buscar un cliente por su nombre , estaba intentándolo yo pero me cuesta mucho entenderlo y he buscado por internet y no me sale nada.

```
public void anadirCliente(ArrayList <Peluqueria> peluqueria){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    String nom;
    String edat;
    String barrio;
    int cua=0;
    System.out.println("Introduce Nombre");
    nom=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduce Edad");
    edat=input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Introduce barrio");
    barrio=input.nextLine();
    cua++;

    peluqueria.add(new Peluqueria(nom,edat,barrio,cua));

}
public void mostrarClientes(ArrayList <Peluqueria> peluqueria){
    for (int i=0;i<peluqueria.size();i++){
        System.out.println(peluqueria.get(i));
    }
}
public void actualizarClientes(ArrayList<Peluqueria> peluqueria){


}
public void buscarClientes(ArrayList <Peluqueria> peluqueria, String barrio){

    for(int i = 0; i<peluqueria.size(); i++){
        if(peluqueria.get(i).getBarrio().equalsIgnoreCase(barrio))
            System.out.println(peluqueria.get(i));
    }
}

public void borrarClientes(ArrayList <Peluqueria> peluqueria, String nom){
    for (int i=0;i<peluqueria.size();i++){
        System.out.println(peluqueria.get(i));
    }
    peluqueria.remove(nom);
}
public void serveisClients(ArrayList <Peluqueria> peluqueria){
    String [] serveis=new String[4];

}
public void solicitarServei(String [] serveis){

}



}
```

La salida es :

```
1-Añadir Cliente
2-Mostrar Clientes
3-Actualizar cliente
4-Mostrar Cliente según el barrio
5-Borrar Cliente
6-Salir
1
Introduce Nombre
Josep
Introduce Edad
15
Introduce barrio
Nou Barris
1-Añadir Cliente
2-Mostrar Clientes
3-Actualizar cliente
4-Mostrar Cliente según el barrio
5-Borrar Cliente
6-Salir
5
Seleccione el cliente a borrar:
peluqueria{nom='Josep', edat='15', barrio='Nou Barris', cua=1}
1-Añadir Cliente
2-Mostrar Clientes
3-Actualizar cliente
4-Mostrar Cliente según el barrio
5-Borrar Cliente
6-Salir
2
peluqueria{nom='Josep', edat='15', barrio='Nou Barris', cua=1}
1-Añadir Cliente
2-Mostrar Clientes
3-Actualizar cliente
4-Mostrar Cliente según el barrio
5-Borrar Cliente
6-Salir
```

intento borrar pero no borra

Comment: Primeramente `buscarClientes` y `borrarClientes` no son clases, son métodos. Luego, para buscar el cliente o borrarlo, deberías añadir al método un parámetro con el dato a buscar y lo mismo debería ocurrir con `borrarClientes`. En ese método cometes un grave error metiendo dentro de èl un `Scanner`... Otra cosa que te recomiendo es que uses la *convención de nombre* recomendada para Java: los nombres de clase, como `peluqueria`, deberían estar escritos con la 1ª letra en mayúscula: `Peluqueria`, así el código es menos confuso.

Comment: Vale, Muchas Gracias me habia confundido he puesto clase en vez de métodos sorry

Comment: Revisa lo otro que te he sugerido y dinos si funciona o qué error tienes, editando la pregunta con el código corregido.

Comment: ¿Por qué hablas de clientes todo el rato pero la clase se llama Peluquería? Deberías aclararte los conceptos antes de continuar, renombrando la clase o los métodos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta cambiar el metodo borrar clientes por este

```
 public void borrarClientes(ArrayList <Peluqueria> peluqueria, String nom){
    for (int i=0;i<peluqueria.size();i++){
       if(peluqueria.get(i).getNombre().equalsIgnoreCase(nom){
             peluqueria.remove(i);
       }
    }
}
```

Eso si que yo supuse que tienes un metodo getNombre en la clase peluqueria. Y otra cosa solo es necesario que pidas el nombre por consola y tan solo con el nombre quitar de la lista el elemento